# SQL Server to convert date as text into date format that is recognised in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I've got data in SQL Server that is text formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd` I've converted this into UK date format as follows

```
convert (varchar (10), main.Tbl_ServiceOrder.SOCreatedOn, 103) as SOCreated
```

I'm then importing the data into Excel via a SQL Server table, but although the date appears correctly (`dd/mm/yyyy`), Excel still recognises it as text.

I can convert it in Excel via DateValue but as the dataset is large I'm trying to get as much done in SQL.

Comment: Have you tried to add 0 to text date and then apply the formula on all cells? https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/26/excel-convert-text-date/

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using excel to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in past. For me, casting date column to smalldatetime worked.

```
CAST(convert (varchar (10), main.Tbl_ServiceOrder.SOCreatedOn, 103) AS smalldatetime)
```

Try it may work for you as well.

Comment: The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Is this because its looking for a time value and the source date doesn't have a time?

Comment: fixed it I had to add [set dateformat dmy] to the start of my query. thanks

Comment: Ohh right. You were using different date format. Does it solves your excel import issue?

Comment: I didn't even have to convert to varchar. Casting to smalldatetime was enough for excel to recognize it as date. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for a solution to get a date format 23 ( which is YYYY-MM-DD) to come into Excel as a date type field.  It would come in as a text value of "2020-01-01" for example even though the cell format was date (MM/DD/YY).  I have no choice but to run this macro to convert it to a date.

```
Cells.Replace What:="-", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Or if yours is coming in with backslash:

```
Cells.Replace What:="/", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

It wasn't a problem for me because I was already using a macro to run the query for the data in the first place.